# Query Multiple Tables SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
CUSTOMER TABLE
id | customerID | name | lastname
1  | 0001       | John | Doe

ANSWERS TABLE
id | customerID | status | date
1  | 0001       | 0      | 2014-05-26

ANSWERMETAS TABLE
id | answerID   | questionCode
1  | 1          | 50000
2  | 1          | 60000
```

How can I query all the customers tables together with their answers?

Comment: a.) DON'T SHOUT and 2.) Have you tried anything?

Comment: RTFM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: If you tried that @solomonculaste then what was the problem? Did you get back a result set you weren't expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$customers = DB::table('customer')
          ->join('answers', 'customer.customerID', '=', 'answers.customerID')
          ->join('answermetas', 'answers.id', '=', 'answermetas.answerID')
          ->get();
```

If you have `Eloquent` models for those tables then you may use `Eloquent` relationship and `Eloquent` methods instead but this will work as well. Also make sure your table name `customer` is right (could be customers).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    customers
JOIN
    answers ON customers.customerID = answers.customerID
JOIN
    answermetas ON answers.id = answermetas.answerID
```

If you want to add any `WHERE` clauses, you'll need to list `table.column_name` instead of just `column_name` because we have joined multiple tables and now column names can be ambiguous (ie. `id` is ambiguous so call `customers.id` or `answers.id` or `answermetas.id`). The result will have all field names as `table.column_name`